# what is a coloring in set theory?

Tags: set-theory, coloring

I've been interested in the Open Coloring Axiom,  but I couldn't find a formal definition for Coloring. Is there an actual definition for Coloring? Is a coloring a function?

Comment: A coloring in set theory is a fancy appellation for a specific partition of a set or a graph into a certain number of pieces.

Answer (score 2):

A coloring of a set $A$ with a set $C$ of colors is a function $f:A\to C$.  Usually (and in particular in OCA) the set $A$ being colored is obtained from some other set $X$, for example as the set of $2$-element subsets of $X$.

A coloring $f$ as above is almost equivalent to a partition of $A$ into pieces indexed by $C$, namely the pieces $f^{-1}(\{c\})$ for $c\in C$. Here "almost" refers to the detail that pieces in a partition are supposed to be nonempty, whereas $f$ is not required to be surjective.

Comment: ... and even more specifically in the context of OCA, i.e., of 2-colourings with one colour $c_0$ designated, we can even identify $f$ simply with $f^{-1}(\{c_0\})$, in other words with an arbitrary subset of $A$.